# GNU make strange behaviour

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can't get my head around the following behaviour of (gnu) make. Here is a minimal project to reproduce the problem:

Source tree:

```
project/
    foo.c
    include/
        foo.h
    main.c
    makefile
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

foo.h

```
/* blank */
```

main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
CC           = gcc
INCLUDE      = include
INCLUDE_HDRS = $(shell echo $(INCLUDE)/*.h)
SOURCES      = $(filter-out main.c, $(shell echo *.c))
HEADERS      = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS      = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS) $(INCLUDE_HDRS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I./$(INCLUDE)

all: main.c $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $< $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f a.out
```

This does not build, producing the following error:

```
~$ make
gcc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
foo.c:1:10: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
 #include "foo.h"
      ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: foo.o] Error 1
```

The compilation command is somehow missing the -I./include flag. However, if I add any .h file to the project's root directory, it builds fine. I believe, that with no .h file in the root directory, the shell function produces garbage, but how can this affect the way the compilation command is constructed?

Just in case: this is GNU Make 4.2.1, gcc version 7.2.1 on linux.

Comment: Can you try to substitute the `$(shell echo ` calls with `$(wildcard `? BTW why do you list `main.c` as an extra dependency for `all`?

Comment: $(wildcard .h) really works! But I still do not understand why it acts like this as it is. I need main.c as dependency, since the %.o rule only builds the objects apart from main (I filter it out in the SOURCES variable). This is a rudiment from my real project, though I now see it is not necessary to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Wildcard expansion is failing because you have no headers in the root dir, which causes the rule itself to fail (it ends up looking for a file with the literal name `*.h`), but as it's a pattern rule and make has a built-in rule available for `%.o`, it picks this instead of giving an error. As @Vroomfondel points out you need to use the `wildcard` function.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the built-in rule for %.o.